# FileName.println(String); skips every other line

Tags: java, line, printwriter

I have to modify measurmentdata from an experiment in a .txt-file. What I've tried to do is to read one line at a time from the file, modify it, and then write it to a new file. However, my output file only contains every other line from the input. Could somebody please explain my error?

```java
import java.io.*;

public class TextMod {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\ediwi\\Desktop\\Exfys A\\Java\\Code\\DataPointsModded.txt");
        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("me99.txt"));
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)));
        int counter = 0;

        while (true) {
            String s = inFile.readLine();
            if (counter < 11) { // I want to skip the first couple of lines
                counter++;
                continue;
            } else if (inFile.readLine() == null) {
                System.out.println(counter - 11 + "Datapoints.");
                break;
            } else outFile.println(s.replaceAll("\\t", ";"));
            counter++;
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: In `else if (inFile.readLine() == null)` use the variable (`s`)- do not read further.

Comment: In order to skip every other line use `modulo` operand `counter % 2 == 0`

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you very much! @PM 77-1

Answer (score 1):

The error was in line 21, as pointed out in a comment above by PM 77-1:

`} else if (inFile.readLine() == null) {`

It should be

`} else if (s == null) {`